# increasing legend line width and remove circle in legend

Tags: jpgraph

I have to add two function in jpgraph. 
1. incresing legend line width
2. remove circle in legend

I can set the line weight of the Legend. but not able to set the width and remove the circle mark in legend. But want to show circle mark in the line graph.

```
$datay1 = array(20,15,23,15);

// Setup the graph
$graph = new Graph(300,250);
$graph->SetScale("textlin");
$graph->title->Set('Filled Y-grid');
$graph->SetBox(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideZeroLabel();
$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);
$graph->xgrid->Show();
$graph->xgrid->SetLineStyle("solid");
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('A','B','C','D'));
$graph->xgrid->SetColor('#E3E3E3');

// Create the first line
$p1 = new LinePlot($datay1);
$graph->Add($p1);
$p1->SetColor("red"); 
$p1->SetWeight(2); 
$p1->SetLegend('Line 1');
$p1->mark->SetType(MARK_FILLEDCIRCLE);
$p1->mark->SetFillColor('#FFFFFF'); 
$graph->legend->SetFrameWeight(0);
$graph->legend->SetLineWeight(3);  
$graph->legend->SetPos(0.03,0.87,'left','bottom');

// Output line
$graph->Stroke();
```

sample data and pic are attached... 
[image]

any idea appreciated .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible, but a workaround to get the desired result is to add the following to your code:

```
$graph->legend->SetMarkAbsVSize(0);
```

And then edit the jpgraph_legend.inc.php. Look for the lines:

```
$p[2]->Stroke($aImg,$x1,$marky);
```

and replace them with:

```
if ($this->mark_abs_vsize !=0) $p[2]->Stroke($aImg,$x1,$marky);
```

Now the marks will not appear if the SetMarkAbsVSize is set to zero.

The line width is always the same as the line width in the plot.